# Grandtotal at the end of final page in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to calculate the grand total at the end of the final page of my gridview. Right now, I am getting total at the end of each page. I don't want total at the end of each page, I want total at the end of the final page. Here is what I have so far that calculated the total at the end of each page.

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataSet ds = new Projects.getdataa();
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        grdDateReport.DataSource = ds;
        columnCount = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;

        grdDateReport.DataBind();
        CalculateTotalHours();
    }
}
```

My gridview looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDateReport" OnRowDataBound="grdDateReport_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="Server" AllowPaging="true" CssClass="GridView1"
    Font-Names="Arial" PageSize="25" Width="90%" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" ShowFooter="true"
    BorderWidth="1px" OnPageIndexChanging="grdDateReport_PageIndexChanging" Height="100px" Font-Size="10px" OnDataBound="grdDateReport_DataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#BFE4FF" />
    <HeaderStyle Height="20px" BackColor="#6DC2FF" Font-Size="10px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <RowStyle Height="2px" Font-Size="13px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid"
        BorderWidth="1px" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No Data for the above selections</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

My CalculateTotalHours looks like this

```
private void CalculateTotalHours()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < columnCount - 1; i++)
    {
        double total = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdDateReport.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[i].Text != "&nbsp;")
            {
                total += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[i].Text);
            }
        }
        grdDateReport.FooterRow.Cells[i].Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

My paging is like this

```
protected void grdDateReport_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdDateReport.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

My Gridview looks like this

```
Projects       Test1        Test2       Test3      Test4

 Tickets           8           10         0          0

 maintenance       9          11         13        0


 Writing web       8            9          8        0

  VSS                                                 12.5
```

I need to put the total on final page for Test1, Test2 and Test3. The column numbers can change.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `NewPageIndex` against the total number of pages and show the total in the Footer.

```
protected void grdDateReport_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdDateReport.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindGrid();

    if (grdDateReport.PageCount == e.NewPageIndex + 1)
    {
        grdDateReport.FooterRow.Cells[0].Text = string.Format("{0:N2}", total);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not one total. I need to create total for all the columns except the first column. I edited my post above. My gridview looks like above and has 1000 rows. I am displaying only 25 each page

Comment: You can add as many totals as you want for each column. The question is about the last page of the GridView. In the above if statement you can add all the totals.